# how to display or not display the tables rows or table data using onchange in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code that can select different options. Depending on the selection the rows or the data in the table changes. Here is my html code :

```
Select here <select name='set' id="set" class="selectpicker" onchange='displayFields(this.value);'>
        <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
        <option>Selection 1</option>
        <option>Selection 2</option>
        <option>Selection 3</option>
        <option>Selection 4</option>
    </select> 
<table class="root-table" id="table-root">
    <br/>
     <tr>
        <td><p>foo Name:</p></td>
        <td><p>fooo Name:</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" value=""/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><p>bar:</p></td>
        <td><p>bar2:</p></td>
        <td><p>bar3:</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="bar" name="bar" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><p>foo1:</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="foo1" name="foo1" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="user"><p>UserName   :</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" style='display:none;'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="pass"><p>Password   :</p></td>
        <td><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Here the table data changes when different option is selected. Please see the required output :

```
When Selection 1 is selected
row 1 : foo name : and text field
row 2 : bar : and text field
row 3 : foo1: and text field
row 4 : not displayed
row 5 : Password : and password field

When Selection 2 is selected
row 1 : fooo Name : and text field
row 2 : bar2 : and text field
row 3 : not displayed
row 4 : username and text field
row 5 : Password : and password field

When Selection 3 is selected
row 1 : foo name : and text field
row 2 : bar3 : and text field
row 3 : foo1: and text field
row 4 : username and text field
row 5 : Password : and password field

When Selection 4 is selected
row 1 : foo name : and text field
row 2 : not displayed
row 3 : not displayed
row 4 : username and text field
row 5 : Password : and password field
```

and in my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function displayFields(setType){

            setValue = setType;
            ...
            ...
            ...
</script>
```

The rows which are not display should not be displayed in the page even if the css for that table is been used.

I tried to use `display=block` and `document.getElementById("").style.visibility = 'visible' or 'none';` but this has too many holes and i find it unreliable.
Can you help me find a solution for this problem.

NOTE : it doesn't matter the solution is javascript or JQuery anything that works without any issues.

Comment: Put different class on each `<tr>` . Then use jquery .change() to detect option change and then use if else to .hide()  , .show()  base on ur requirement.

Comment: If you use bootstrap template ,you can use .toggleClass('hidden´)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using jQuery. It's fairly flexible, based on using CSS classes to group elements, so if you add more options or more rules, you just need to put the appropriate classes on the elements affected - without changing the javascript code. The system is very simple: on the affected elements, there's a class of the form "display-x" where "x" is the value of the option in the select. If an option is selected, then all elements within the table with that class will be set visible, all others will be hidden.

(Note some elements, e.g. `<tr>`s have got classes, because they contain elements that need to be shown, and that tr might have been hidden by an earlier selection).

```
Select here <select name='set' id="set" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="" selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
    <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
    <option value="3">Selection 3</option>
    <option value="4">Selection 4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<table class="root-table" id="table-root">
<tbody>
<tr class="display-1 display-2 display-3 display-4">
    <td class="display-1 display-3 display-4"><p>foo Name:</p></td>
    <td class="display-2"><p>fooo Name:</p></td>
    <td class="display-1 display-2 display-3 display-4" ><input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="display-1 display-2 display-3">
    <td class="display-1"><p>bar:</p></td>
    <td class="display-2"><p>bar2:</p></td>
    <td class="display-3"><p>bar3:</p></td>
    <td class="display-1 display-2 display-3"><input type="text" id="bar" name="bar" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="display-1 display-3">
    <td class="display-1 display-3"><p>foo1:</p></td>
    <td class="display-1 display-3"><input type="text" id="foo1" name="foo1" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="display display-2 display-3 display-4">
    <td id="user" class="display display-2 display-3 display-4"><p>UserName   :</p></td>
    <td class="display display-2 display-3 display-4"><input type="text" id="uid" name="uid"/></td>
</tr>

<tr class="display-1 display-2 display-3 display-4">
    <td id="pass" class="display-1 display-2 display-3 display-4"><p>Password   :</p></td>
    <td class="display-1 display-2 display-3 display-4"><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#table-root tbody").find("tr, td").hide(); //hide all row and cell elements to begin with

  $("#set").change(function() {
    $("#table-root tbody").find("tr, td").hide(); //hide all row and cell elements
    $("#table-root .display-" + $(this).val()).show(); //show only those elements which match the current selection
  });   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the comment on your question says. I'll just give you a small example with an option for displaying one row.

```
Select here 
<select name='set' id="set" class="selectpicker"    onchange='displayFields(this.value);'>
       <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
       <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
       <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
       <option value="3">Selection 3</option>
       <option value="4">Selection 4</option>
</select> 
.
.
.
<tr id="row1">
    <td><p>foo Name:</p></td>
    <td><p>fooo Name:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" value=""/></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#row1').hide();

    $('#set').change(function(){
       if(("#set").val()==1){
          $('#row1').show();
       }
    }

 }
```

Do the same for the rest. Should work.

Comment: then what can i do to change between the `<td>foo and fooo`

Comment: read the requirements more carefully. OP is asking for different parts of each row to be shown/hidden as well.

Comment: yes that too is also there and also i need to hide the <td> for certain rows also